# Not able to use COUNT properly in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query already written which returns some result

```
MATCH(n:Prop)
        WHERE toLower(n.Type)=toLower("abc") 
        WITH n.Id AS id, n
        MATCH (new:op)
        WHERE new.Id STARTS WITH id
        WITH new,n 
        MATCH (o:`here`)-[:Property]->(new) 
        WHERE (o:Obj) 
        WITH Count(DISTINCT o) AS languages,n,new
    return count(n)
```

This returns me count 6 which is expected
But since I want the id as well I change the query as

```
MATCH(n:Prop)
        WHERE toLower(n.Type)=toLower("abc") 
        WITH n.Id AS id, n
        MATCH (new:op)
        WHERE new.Id STARTS WITH id
        WITH new,n 
        MATCH (o:`here`)-[:Property]->(new) 
        WHERE (o:Obj) 
        WITH Count(DISTINCT o) AS languages,n,new
    return count(n), id(n)
```

The problem with this is that I get the count as one with each id but I want the totalCount which was 6 only with each row

I have tried many different things but couldnt get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect and unwind all the nodes, like this:

```
MATCH(n:Prop)
WHERE toLower(n.Type)=toLower("abc") 
WITH n.Id AS id, n
MATCH (new:op)
WHERE new.Id STARTS WITH id
WITH new,n 
MATCH (o:`here`)-[:Property]->(new) 
WHERE (o:Obj) 
WITH Count(DISTINCT o) AS languages, n, new
WITH count(n) as nodesCount, COLLECT(n.Id) as ids
UNWIND ids as nodeId
RETURN nodesCount, nodeId
```

Comment: I am somewhat able to get the correct count but the result is not correct since I am receiving cross multiplication of the results
i HAVE MORE THAN 2 FIELDS

Comment: Can you add your expected result in the question and what are you currently getting? @rohitbumrah

Answer (score 0):

Swap the places of the fields in your return. The reason for that is that Cypher does implicit aggregation, so it will aggregate on each field in the list in written order. In your example, it will group first on `count(n)`, then on `id(n)`. I think you want to group on the count for each id. Updated Cypher is below.

```
MATCH(n:Prop)
    WHERE toLower(n.Type)=toLower("abc") 
    WITH n.Id AS id, n
    MATCH (new:op)
    WHERE new.Id STARTS WITH id
    WITH new,n 
    MATCH (o:`here`)-[:Property]->(new) 
    WHERE (o:Obj) 
    WITH Count(DISTINCT o) AS languages,n,new
return id(n), count(n)
```